# .htaccess Rewrite causing index.php to not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite conditions which allow me to 1) Access pages without.php extension, and 2) Makes the site directly access files in the /pages/ directory.

For some reason, I cannot access index.php of the folder via the URL as url.com/profile , I have to do it as url.com/profile/index

The url.com/profile works to access the index when I delete one of the two rules mentioned above, but not when both are added. Am I doing something wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d      
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1
```

Comment: Is `index.php` in `/pages/profile` or `/profile`?

Comment: It is - I can access it when I got pages/profile/index but not pages/profile

Comment: Can you show the file structure? It’s hard to answer this question without that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rules,

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d      
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1
```